# Hashing, MurmurHash

Tags: algorithm

I used Murmur hash to hash around 800 000 string values, and this cause many conflicts (collision), that around 17 collision (different strings give the same hash value), is this normal, any one know the quality of murmur hash function

Comment: Not familiar with murmur hash function, but Hash functions are prone to have some collisions.

Answer (score 4):

Check [this excellent answer on programmers.stackexhange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633/78464) which compares various hash algorithms including Mumurhash2 (but not Mumurhash3) for speed, collisions, and randomness.

Answer (score 2):

This [comparison of hashing functions](http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions) seems to indicate that Murmurhash generates roughly the same number of collisions as alternate hashes over a wide range of input data.

Answer (score 0):

And note that Murmur 2.0 had a small flaw that was since fixed in a new version of the hash http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/